# How can I develop windows phone 7.8 apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7.8

I updated WP7.8 Sdk to my computer(win7), but I can't see any change except a WP7.8 emulator, how can I use those new WP7.8 APIs? For example, how to create a Flip Tile with WP7.8 Sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP8 is the new API. WP7.8 is only a better UI with tiles, WP7.8 still be WP7.5 no new API for this version.